# Actionsciprt 3 How to Accelerometer

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cc

I am about to create a 2D car racing game using `accelerometer`, The problem is the car position on the screen, that when the game starts, the car appears at the left side while expected to be at the center. 
How can I solve it?

```
private var accelerometer: Accelerometer;
    var accelX: Number;

    public function game() {
    if (Accelerometer.isSupported) {
        car.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveCar);

        accelerometer = new Accelerometer();
        accelerometer.addEventListener(AccelerometerEvent.UPDATE, AccelerometerUpdateHandler);

    }
    }

    function AccelerometerUpdateHandler(event: AccelerometerEvent): void {
        accelX = event.accelerationX;
    }

    function moveCar(evt: Event) {
        car.x -= accelX * 30;

        if (car.x > 299) {
            car.x = 299;
        } else if (car.x < 110) {
            car.x = 110;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please provide a additional information about the technology you are using and the X and Y axis direction, which will be very nice if you upload some pictures, however since your reputation is low it wouldn't let you embed any picture, but you are welcome to upload pictures somewhere and use their link in your question, So please edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To centre a MovieClip to the stage at the start of app you need to get the stage width, divide this by 2 and then take away had of the car's width (unless the car is cent erred inside its MovieClip?)

```
car.x = (stage.stageWidth /2) - (car.width /2)
```